# strtok crash Not sure why its bugging

Tags: c

In the strtok it doesnt even give me and error it just crashes, below the g->db_cmd is a char*, can anyone help me out with this issue thank you for the help in advance.

```
short processCMD(i_gsd_ptr g, i_exit_cb_ptr i_exit_cb, char* i_cmd )
{

  /*-------------------LOCAL VARIABLES-----------------*/
  struct local_stack_def
  {
   char delims[3];
   int x;
   short cmd_match, error,len_eulm,range_eulm, imp_eulm, sub_cmd_match;
   short* cmd_len;
   short* db_len;
   char val_cmd[10];
   _cc_status cc;
   char DataEntry[400];
   char msg_eulm[400];
   char* cmd;
   char* db_cmd;
   char space_const[2]; 
   char *result;
   char del_const[2];
  };

  short  pool_err;
  struct local_stack_def *l;

  #pragma nowarn (30)
  l  = POOL_GETSPACE_(i_exit_cb->Pool_addr,sizeof(struct local_stack_def),&pool_err );
  #pragma warn
  if (pool_err != 0)
  {
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  l->x = 1;
  l->cmd_match=0;
  *l->db_len = 0;
  l->db_cmd = g->db_cmd;
  l->imp_eulm= 1;
  #pragma nowarn (207)
  strncpy(l->del_const,"~",2);
  #pragma warn


   l->result = strtok( g->db_cmd,l->del_const);
   strcpy(l->db_cmd,l->result);
```

Comment: the g->dn_cmd contains the valid data "this~string~"

Comment: What warnings are you suppressing using the `#pragma nowarn` directives?

Comment: Have you checked that ``l->del_const`` is a valid pointer?

Comment: l->del_const conatins '~''\0'

Comment: @Praetorian code space taken because im in a different env

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` loops through the string it is tokenizing and replaces the delimiter characters with `'\0'`. So, if `g->db_cmd` points to a read-only string literal your `strtok` call will crash.